# NameError: "global name 'ptint_lol' is not defined"

Tags: python

I'm a green hand writing python,so I bought 'Head First Python'.When I try to run the cases given in the book, I got this :NameError: "global name 'ptint_lol' is not defined".
Here is the code,and the version of python is 3.4

```
movies=["The Holy Grail",1975,"Terry Jones & Terry Gilliam",91,
    ["Graham Chapman",["Michael Palin","John Cleese",
                      "Terrt Gilliam","Eric Idle","Terry Jones"]]]
def print_lol(the_list):
   for each_item in the_list:
        if isinstance(each_item,list):
            ptint_lol(each_item)
        else:
            print (each_item)
print_lol(movies)
```

It's just a stupid typo. So sorry about wasting you guys' precious time.

Comment: It's a typo in the recursive call: `ptint_lol(each_item)` should be `prtint_lol(each_item)`, missing **r**.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: **Head First Pythom** book has a typo, is it? :)

Comment: It's my fault,not the book's.I'm so sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant to type `print_lol(each_item)`

And either way, this still won't work. You should *return* the values instead of printing them. So do:

```
return print_lol(each_item)
```

And:

```
return each_item
```

Comment: thk u,but it seems to be just a typo. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I realized that code you posted it is ok. But the one you have in your project maybe not.

Take a look to the error, the function name is misspelled.